# Prevent jquery fadeIn many times

Tags: javascript, jquery

Need to prevent the emergence of tips several times (when not a single clue pointing at a link persists even if the cursor is not on a link).

```
$(function () {
 $(".area_tooltip").mouseover(function () {
   var tooltip = $("div#" + $(this).attr("id") + "");
   tooltip.fadeIn();
  }).mouseout(function () {
   var tooltip = $("div#" + $(this).attr("id") + "");
   tooltip.fadeOut();
  });
});
```

To understand the problem to move the red square over several times, and then remove it in the direction

http://jsfiddle.net/8LnTC/1/

I apologize for my bad English

Comment: Ehm, why don't you use `$(this).fadeOut()` or do you have duplicate ID's? If so, ID's must be unique, use class instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to stop any queued animations first...

```
$(function () {
    $(".area_tooltip").mouseover(function () {
        var tooltip = $("div#" + $(this).attr("id") + "");
        tooltip.stop().fadeIn();
    }).mouseout(function () {
        var tooltip = $("div#" + $(this).attr("id") + "");
        tooltip.stop().fadeOut();
    });
});
```

**[Working jsfiddle example...](http://jsfiddle.net/ArchersFiddle/8LnTC/2/)**

Incidentally, you shouldn't have multiple elements with the same ID.  You need to rethink how you're going to relate the elements to each other - maybe use data attributes.

Here's a suggested alternative...

**[Working jsfiddle example...](http://jsfiddle.net/ArchersFiddle/8LnTC/4/)**

**HTML change**

```
<a class="area_tooltip" data-associated-tooltip="item_1">show</a>
```

**Javascript change**

```
$(function () {
    $(".area_tooltip").mouseover(function () {
        var tooltip = $("div#" + $(this).data("associated-tooltip"));
        tooltip.stop().fadeIn();
    }).mouseout(function () {
        var tooltip = $("div#" + $(this).data("associated-tooltip"));
        tooltip.stop().fadeOut();
    });
});
```

You put the tip's ID in the attribute `data-associated-tooltip` and then you can access that with `$(this).data("associated-tooltip")`.  That will get rid of any ID conflicts which will most likely cause untold problems.